# How to handle data binding in Rails while using React.js for the front end?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs

I am interested in building an isomorphic application that will use React.js for the front end, and Rails for everything else.

I'm sure I'll be using a decent amount of AJAX, but for primary form submits and page changes I want to go through the Rails router. I don't want to use Javascript to control what views I'm showing on the client.

My only question is, what is the best way to setup my inputs in React so that they bind cleanly with my models in Rails?

In a regular erb you would create a form object for the given model, and then use input methods on that object to create HTML inputs that are already setup so that when you submit, data binding is pretty much automatic.

The only way I can think of to do this with something like React, is to manually set the `name` attribute on my inputs so that they get bound correctly. I guess that's not terrible, I'm just wondering if anyone has a better solution.

Comment: Isomorphic? Same Code on Server and client? you want rails to use react instead of ERB? can you clarify?

Answer (score 0):

Create a client side(React model) to "reflect" the rails response.
For example on the rails side:

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :thread

  validate :text, presence: true
end
```

The JSON response sent by the server index / new endpoint should define the data model structure on the client side. For example the index endpoint could return:

```
{
  "messages": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "text": "Hello Stack",
      "threadId": "5"
    } 
  ]
}
```

Client side model:

```
var Message = function Model(){
  this.id = null;
  this.text = null;
  this.threadId = null;
};

Message.fromJSON = function(messageJSON) {
  var message = new Message();
  message.id = messageJSON.id;
  // ...
  return message;
};

module.exports = Message;
```

Then on create / edit, just call JSON.stringfy(msg).